# How to add custom JS to Django model admin

Tags: django

I have a Django model that requires an OAuth token as one of its properties. The easiest way to generate the token is using the supplied client-side JS from the API provider. I'd like to add a simple link to the add/edit template in the Django admin site to invoke this JS and put the resulting token into the appropriate field - see attached as an example of where I'm trying to get to.

[image]

I've read the [Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates) documentation, but that doesn't cover this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite `django/contrib/templates/admin/change_form.html`

```
{% extends "/admin/change_form.html" %}

    {% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks @woldendranh - this is part of the solution: adding in the client.js script. The other part is how to get the link onto the page next to the input field, which I've done using a custom `forms.TextInput` widget that overrides the `render()` method to add in the link. (https://github.com/yunojuno/django-trello-webhooks/blob/master/trello_webhooks/forms.py)